# Is there a quicker way to test css.less changes?

Tags: magento2

When making changes to my *css*.less file for my extension, I have to keep clearing my **Static Files** to see the css changes take effect in the browser.

I'm already in **Developer Mode**, but is there a quicker way to view my changes when I refresh my browser other than clearing the **Static Files** each time I make a change I want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I'm after does seem achievable via a backend setting. You can change the compiler from Server-side to Client-side:

```
STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Front-end development workflow > Workflow type.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Grunt to compile LESS file. Here is the steps:

1. Install Grunt using npm:

   ```
   npm install -g grunt-cli
   cd <your_Magento_instance_directory>
   npm install
   npm update
   ```
2. Rename `Gruntfile.js.sample` to `Gruntfile.js`
3. Go to `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` and add the following section:

   ```
   <theme_name>: {
       area: 'frontend',
       name: '<Vendor>/<theme>',
       locale: '<theme_locale>', 
       files: [
           '<css_file_paths>',
       ],
       dsl: 'less'
   },
   ```
4. After editing your LESS file, run this commands:

   ```
   grunt clean
   grunt exec:<theme_name>
   grunt less:<theme_name>
   ```

Refresh the page and you can see the changes.

5. Finally run this command to watch changes automatically

   ```
   grunt watch
   ```

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html